# How to set/make "Different Tab Title" based on the Routes/Pages in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, routes, page-title

Can't use "useParams" or "useLocation" hooks in App.js component to try a Switch Case there! Is There any other Solution except installing react npm Package managers?

or except using this function below in every component.

I will be happy if I get a single function to have the solution of my problem.
Thanks in advance.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
useEffect(() => {
document.title = 'My Page Title';
}, []);
```

Comment: Why can't you use "useParams" or "useLocation"? Are you using react router or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a constant of string based on routes and implment it in _app.jsx

```
const tabTitle ={
"/home":"Home Page",
"/profile":"My Profile Page",
}
```

In Render of _app.jsx

```
 <Head>
        <title>{tabTitle[window.location.pathname] || "My Site"}</title>
 </Head>
```